# Trigonometry to the 24th power

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How can I find the value of
$$\sin^{24}\frac{\pi}{24} + \cos^{24}\frac{\pi}{24}$$
Specifically, is there some easy method that I am overlooking?

Comment: These answer's are really gonna make me cry :'D Well explained :)

Comment: This is the best title I have ever seen on any MSE question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First note that this is the simplest solution that I know. It may or may not be the simplest one. Edit: You can take Micah's path for a simpler solution.

We know that:
$$\cos{\frac{\pi}{6}} = \frac {\sqrt{3}}{2}\quad \Rightarrow 2\cos^2{\frac{\pi}{12}} - 1 = \frac {\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
$$\Rightarrow 2(2\cos^2{\frac{\pi}{24}} -1)^2 - 1= \frac {\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
$$\Rightarrow 8\cos^4{\frac{\pi}{24}}-8\cos^2{\frac{\pi}{24}} + 1 = \frac {\sqrt{3}}{2} $$
$$\Rightarrow 16\cos^4{\frac{\pi}{24}}-16\cos^2{\frac{\pi}{24}} + 2 - \sqrt{3} = 0 $$
$$\Rightarrow \cos^2{\frac{\pi}{24}} = \frac {2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}{4}\quad \Rightarrow \sin^2{\frac{\pi}{24}} = \frac {2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}{4} $$
Now,
$$\sin^{24}{\frac{\pi}{24}} + \cos^{24}{\frac{\pi}{24}} = (\sin^2{\frac{\pi}{24}})^{12} + (\cos^2{\frac{\pi}{24}})^{12}$$
$$= \left( \frac {2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}{4}\right)^{12} + \left( \frac {2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}{4}\right)^{12} $$
$$= \dfrac{1}{4^{12}} \left[ \left( 2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}} \right)^{12} + \left( 2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}} \right)^{12} \right] $$
$$= \dfrac{2}{4^{12}} \left[ 2^{12} + \begin{pmatrix} 12 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} (2^{10}) (\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}})^{2} + \begin{pmatrix} 12 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix} (2^{8}) (\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}})^{4} \\ \quad +\begin{pmatrix} 12 \\ 6 \end{pmatrix} (2^{6}) (\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}})^{6} + \begin{pmatrix} 12 \\ 8 \end{pmatrix} (2^{4}) (\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}})^{8} \\ \quad + \begin{pmatrix} 12 \\ 10 \end{pmatrix} (2^{2}) (\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}})^{10} + \begin{pmatrix} 12 \\ 12 \end{pmatrix} (\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}})^{12} \right] $$
$$= \dfrac{2}{4^{12}} \left[ 2^{12} + \begin{pmatrix} 12 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} (2^{10}) (2+\sqrt{3}) + \begin{pmatrix} 12 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix} (2^{8}) (2+\sqrt{3})^{2} \\ \quad +\begin{pmatrix} 12 \\ 6 \end{pmatrix} (2^{6}) (2+\sqrt{3})^{3} + \begin{pmatrix} 12 \\ 8 \end{pmatrix} (2^{4}) (2+\sqrt{3})^{4} \\ \quad + \begin{pmatrix} 12 \\ 10 \end{pmatrix} (2^{2}) (2+\sqrt{3})^{5} + \begin{pmatrix} 12 \\ 12 \end{pmatrix} (2+\sqrt{3})^{6} \right] $$
$$= \dfrac{1}{8388608} \left[ 4096 + (66)(1024)(2+\sqrt{3}) +(495)(256)(7+4\sqrt{3}) \\ \quad +(924)(64)(26+15\sqrt{3}) +(495)(16)(97+56\sqrt{3}) \\ \quad +(66)(4)(362+209\sqrt{3}) + (1351+780\sqrt{3}) \right] $$
$$= \dfrac {3428999+1960980\sqrt{3}}{8388608}$$

Comment: This is the path I was going to take. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, but if you're looking for a shorter solution, Micah has the shorter/reasonable one.

Answer (score 41):

I would use complex exponentials. We have:
\begin{align}
\sin^{24}\frac{\pi}{24}+\cos^{24}\frac{\pi}{24}&=
  \left(\frac{e^{i\frac{\pi}{24}}-e^{-i\frac{\pi}{24}}}{2i}\right)^{24}
  +\left(\frac{e^{i\frac{\pi}{24}}+e^{-i\frac{\pi}{24}}}{2}\right)^{24}\\
 &=\frac{1}{2^{24}}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{24}\binom{24}{k} (-1)^k e^{i \frac{24-2k}{24}\pi}\right)
  +\frac{1}{2^{24}}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{24}\binom{24}{k} e^{i \frac{24-2k}{24}\pi}\right)\\
 &= \frac{1}{2^{23}}\sum_{l=0}^{12} \binom{24}{2l} e^{i \frac{12 - 2l}{12}\pi}
\end{align}
after canceling every other term in the two sums. We can rewrite this last expression in terms
of trig functions again, as
$$
\frac{1}{2^{22}} \left(\sum_{m=0}^{5} \binom{24}{2m} \cos \left(\pi-\frac{m\pi}{6}\right) +
 \frac{1}{2} \binom{24}{12}\right)
$$
(here we're folding the sum in half and taking advantage of the fact that
$\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n-k}$, which is why the middle term is anomalous).

Now, as $\cos x=-\cos(\pi - x)$, this collapses to a reasonable number of terms:
$$
\frac{1}{2^{22}}\left[\frac{1}{2}\binom{24}{12} - 1 
+ \left(\binom{24}{10} - \binom{24}{2}\right) \cos \frac{\pi}{6}
+ \left(\binom{24}{8} - \binom{24}{4}\right) \cos \frac{\pi}{3}
\right] 
$$
which simplifies into
$$
\frac{1}{2^{22}} \left(\frac{3428999}{2} + 1960980\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)
=\frac{3428999 + 1960980 \sqrt{3}}{2^{23}}
$$

Comment: This is a neat solution.

Comment: Great Solution. +1

Answer (score 33):

Let:
$$ a_n = \sin^{2n}\frac{\pi}{24}+\cos^{2n}\frac{\pi}{24}.\tag{1}$$
Then trivially $a_0=2,a_1=1$ and:
$$ a_n - a_1 a_{n-1} = -\left(\sin^2\frac{\pi}{24}\cos^2\frac{\pi}{24}\right) a_{n-2}\tag{2} $$
so that $a_{12}$ can be computed in a few steps through the recurrence:
$$ a_n = a_{n-1}-\frac{2-\sqrt{3}}{16} a_{n-2}.\tag{3}$$

Answer (score 8):

Considering that the answer is apparently
$$ \frac{7 \left(489857+280140 \sqrt{3}\right)}{8388608}, $$
I doubt there's an easy way.

You know $\sin{\frac{\pi}{6}}=\frac{1}{2}$, $\cos{\frac{\pi}{6}}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, so using the half-angle formulae
$$ 2\sin^2{\frac{x}{2}} = 1-\cos{x},\\
2\cos^2{\frac{x}{2}} = 1+\cos{x} $$
will get us to $\sin{\frac{\pi}{24}}$ and $\cos{\frac{\pi}{24}}$, when applied twice.

In particular,
$$ 4\sin^4{\frac{x}{4}} = \left(1-\cos{\frac{x}{2}}\right)^2 = 1+\cos^2{\frac{x}{2}}-2\cos{\frac{x}{2}} \\
4\cos^4{\frac{x}{4}} = \left(1+\cos{\frac{x}{2}}\right)^2 = 1+\cos^2{\frac{x}{2}}+2\cos{\frac{x}{2}} $$
(At this point we see we have the nice identity
$$4(\sin^4{\theta}+\cos^4{\theta}) = 2(1+\cos^2{2\theta}) = 3+\cos{4\theta},$$
although sadly this is not of much help to us here.)

Therefore we need to raise everything to the power $6$, then divide by $4^6=2^{12}$. Set $a=\cos{(x/2)}$, then we have
$$ 4^6 ( \sin^{24}{\frac{x}{4}} + \cos^{24}{\frac{x}{4}} ) = (1-a)^{12}+(1+a)^{12} $$
At this point we break out the binomial theorem, and notice that quite a lot cancels: all the odd terms, in fact. Then
$$ \sin^{24}{\frac{x}{4}} + \cos^{24}{\frac{x}{4}} = \frac{1}{2^5} \left( 1 + a^6 + \binom{12}{2}(a^2 + a^{10}) + \binom{12}{4}(a^4+a^8) + \binom{12}{6}a^6 \right) = \frac{1}{2^{11}}(1+a^{12}+66(a^2+a^{10})+495(a^4+a^8)+924a^6) $$
Right, now the good news is that we don't need to know what $a$ is, just $a^2$. Indeed, the formula above gives
$$ \cos^2{\frac{\pi}{12}} = \frac{1}{2}\left(1+\cos{\frac{\pi}{6}}\right) = \frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{4}. $$
Therefore you just have to find $a^n$ for even $n$ up to $12$.

Answer (score 8):

A note:   A general formula that is applicable is 
\begin{align}
\sin^{4n}\left(\frac{\pi}{4n}\right) + \cos^{4n}\left( \frac{\pi}{4n}\right) = \frac{1}{4^{2n-1}} \left[ \sum_{r=0}^{n-1} \binom{4n}{2r} \cos\left(1 - \frac{r}{n} \right) \pi \, + \frac{1}{2} \binom{4n}{2n} \right].
\end{align}
When $n=6$ this reduces to
\begin{align}
\sin^{24}\left(\frac{\pi}{24}\right) + \cos^{24}\left( \frac{\pi}{24}\right) = \frac{1}{4^{11}} \left[ \sum_{r=0}^{5} \binom{24}{2r} \cos\left(1 - \frac{r}{6} \right) \pi \, + \frac{1}{2} \binom{24}{12} \right].
\end{align}
The remaining details have been given by Micah's solution.

Comment: Reference please.

Comment: @Leucippus Sir please could you evaluate the formula for $n=11?$ I've was unable to evaluate tt myself.

Comment: @Leucippus Or Sir could you please show me how to put the formula into Wolfram Alpha so that I could use it in future for different values of $n?$

Comment: @BetterWorld As it would seem Wolfram Alpha does not like to compute this series. I tested it a few times. In general just type in the latex version of formulas in WA and it will compute what it can.

Comment: @Leucippus Thank you Sir. Sir could you please suggest a value other than 11 for which this series could  computed? Many thanks Sir.

Comment: @Leucippus Sir please would you suggest a different value of $n$ for which $$\sin^{4n}\left(\frac{\pi}{4n}\right) + \cos^{4n}\left( \frac{\pi}{4n}\right)$$ could be evaluated? If it's not too much trouble would it be possible for you to kindly give the answer too? I would be truly grateful if you would please spare the time to do so Sir.

Answer (score 1):

In the hope of evading the prospect of grappling with large binomial coefficients or many nested radicals, we can "compress" the amount of computation *somewhat* by "judicious" choices of trigonometric identities.

Beginning with the "trig-cubed" identities,
$$  \sin^3 x \ \ = \ \ \frac14·[ \ 3 \sin x \ - \ \sin(3x) \ ] \ \ \ , \ \ \  \cos^3 x \ \ = \ \ \frac14·[ \ 3 \cos x \ + \ \cos(3x) \ ] \ \ , $$

we can apply (more familiar) identities to obtain
$$  \sin^6  \left( \frac{\theta}{2} \right) \ \ = \ \ \frac{1}{32}·[ \ 10 \ - \ 15 \cos \theta \ + \ 6 \cos(2 \theta) \ - \ \cos(3 \theta) \ ] \ \ \ , $$
$$ \cos^6  \left( \frac{\theta}{2} \right) \ \ = \ \ \frac{1}{32}·[ \ 10 \ + \ 15 \cos \theta \ + \ 6 \cos(2 \theta) \ + \ \cos(3 \theta) \ ] \ \ . $$

For what follows, using $ \ \theta \ = \ \frac{\pi}{12} \ \ , \ $ we will call
$$ a \ = \ 10 \ \ , \ \  b \ = \ 15 · \cos \left( \frac{\pi}{12} \right) \ = \ 15 · \sqrt{\frac{1 + \cos (\pi/6)}{2}} \ \ = \ \frac{15}{2}  \sqrt{2 + \sqrt3} \ \ \text{or} \ \ \frac{15}{4} (\sqrt2 + \sqrt6) \ \ , $$ $$ c \ = \ 6 · \cos  \left( \frac{\pi}{6} \right) \ = \ 3\sqrt3  \ \ \ , \ \ \ d \ = \ \cos  \left( \frac{\pi}{4} \right) \ = \  \frac{1}{\sqrt2}  \ \ . \ $$
The value we seek is then given by
$$  \sin^{24}\frac{\pi}{24} \ + \ \cos^{24}\frac{\pi}{24} \ \ = \ \ ( \ \sin^6\frac{\pi}{24} \ )^4 \ + \ ( \ \cos^6\frac{\pi}{24} \ )^4 $$
$$ = \ \ \left(\frac{1}{32} \right)^4  · \ [ \ (a \ - \ b \ + \ c \ - \ d \ )^4 \ + \ (a \ + \ b \ + \ c \ + \ d \ )^4 \ ] $$

[we couldn't avoid binomial expansion *forever*...]

$$  = \ \ \left(\frac{1}{32^4} \right)   · \ 2 \ · \ [ \ ( \ a^4 \ + \ b^4 \ + \ c^4 \  + \ d^4 \ )  \ \ + \ \ 4·( \ a^3 c \ + \ a c^3 \ + \ b^3 d \ + \ b d^3 \ )  $$
$$ + \ \ 6·( \ a^2 b^2 \ + \ a^2 c^2 \ + \ a^2 d^2 \ + \ b^2 c^2 \ + \ b^2 d^2 \ + \ c^2 d^2 \ ) $$
$$ + \ \ 12·( \ a^2 bd \ + \ a b^2 c \ + \ a c d^2 \ + \ b c^2 d \ ) \ \ + \ \ 24·abcd \ ] $$

The terms in parentheses are equal to
$$ a^4 \ + \ b^4 \ + \ c^4 \  + \ d^4 \ \ = \ \ 10^4 \ + \ \left(\frac{15}{2} \right)^4·(7 + 4 \sqrt3) \ + \ 3^6 \ + \ \frac{1}{2^2} \ \ ,  $$
$$ a^3 c \ + \ a c^3 \ + \ b^3 d \ + \ b d^3 \ \ = \ \ 10^3·3 \sqrt3 \ + \ 10·3^4·\sqrt3 $$ $$ + \ \left(\frac{15}{2} \right)^3·(4 \sqrt2)·(5 + 3 \sqrt3)·\frac{1}{\sqrt2} \ + \ \frac{15}{4}·(\sqrt2)·(1 + \sqrt3)·\frac{1}{2 \sqrt2} \ \ , $$
$$ a^2 b^2 \ + \ a^2 c^2 \ + \ a^2 d^2 \ + \ b^2 c^2 \ + \ b^2 d^2 \ + \ c^2 d^2 \ \ = \ \ 100·\left(\frac{15}{2} \right)^2·(2 + \sqrt3)   $$
$$ + \ 100·3^3 \ + \ 100·\frac12 \ + \ \left(\frac{15}{2} \right)^2·(2 + \sqrt3)·3^3 \ + \ \left(\frac{15}{2} \right)^2·(2 + \sqrt3)·\frac12 \ + \ 3^3·\frac12 \ \ , $$
$$ a^2 bd \ + \ a b^2 c \ + \ a c d^2 \ + \ b c^2 d \ \ = \ \ 100·\frac{15}{4} ·(\sqrt2)· (1 + \sqrt3)·\frac{1}{\sqrt2} $$
$$ + \ 10·\frac{15^2}{2^2}·(2 + \sqrt3)·(3 \sqrt3) \ + \ 10·(3 \sqrt3)·\frac12 \ + \ \frac{15}{4} ·(\sqrt2)· (1 + \sqrt3)·3^3·\frac{1}{\sqrt2} \ \ , $$
$$ abcd \ \ = \ \ 10·\frac{15}{4} ·(\sqrt2)· (1 + \sqrt3)·(3 \sqrt3)·\frac{1}{\sqrt2} \ \ . $$

What we observe from this collection of terms is that all factors of $ \ \sqrt2 \ $ "cancel", so we expect that $ \  \sin^{24}\frac{\pi}{24} \ + \ \cos^{24}\frac{\pi}{24} \ $ has a value which is the sum of a positive rational number and a positive rational number times $ \ \sqrt3 \ \ . \ $  Sparing the reader the deluge of arithmetic remaining, we determine that

$  \sin^{24}\frac{\pi}{24} \ + \ \cos^{24}\frac{\pi}{24} \   =  $
$$  \frac{1}{2^{19}} \ · \ \left[ \ \left( \  \frac{526043}{16} \ + \ \frac{16905}{4} \ + \ \frac{205287}{2} \ + \ 66465 \ + \ 8100 \right) \ \right. $$
$$ \left. + \ \left( \ \frac{50625}{4} \ + \ \frac{71115}{4} \ + \ \frac{172125}{4} \ + \ 46395 \ + \ 2700 \right)·\sqrt3 \ \right] $$
$$ = \ \ \frac{3428999}{2^{23}} \ + \ \frac{490245}{2^{21}}\sqrt3 \quad \text{or} \quad \frac{3428999 \ + \ 1960980 \sqrt3}{2^{23}} \ \ , $$

confirming the result posted by **user174622** and **Micah**.
$$ \ \ $$

The causes of such a frightful amount of calculation (as presented or implied in the posted answers) are the desire for an *exact* expression for this trigonometric value and the nature of the trigonometric identities.  By contrast, a rather good *estimate* can be easily found by using the approximations
$$ \sin^{24} \frac{\pi}{24} \ + \ \cos^{24} \frac{\pi}{24} \ \  = \ \ \left(\frac{\pi}{24} \right)^{24} \ + \ \left[ \ 1 \ - \ \frac12·\left(\frac{\pi}{24} \right)^2 \ \right]^{24} $$
$$ = \ \  (0.13089969)^{24} \ + \  [ \ 1 \ - \ \frac12·(0.13089969)^2 \ ]^{24} $$
$$  \approx \ \ 6.405·10^{-22} \ + \ (0.99143264)^{24} \ \ \approx \ \ 0.813424 \ \ .  $$
[WolframAlpha shows the numerical value $ \ 0.81366491... \ ] $

So $ \   \sin^{24} \frac{\pi}{24}   +   \cos^{24} \frac{\pi}{24} \ $ is *almost exactly* just the second term $ \  ( \ \cos  \frac{\pi}{24} \ )^{24} \ \ . \ $